# does system monitor use a lot of bandwidth to calculate download/upload speed?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, monitoring

I'm using Ubuntu and `indicator-multiload`. I see a realtime upload/download speed.

I'm wondering if this check itself is taking up bandwidth and if so, if it is a negligable amount or not.

I'm not familiar with a tool to investigate this.

More broadly, I'm asking if the process of monitoring upload/download speed is bandwidth-intensive for a personal computer.

Comment: Does this tool actually send traffic out the interface? If not, it is not using any bandwidth.

Comment: @RonMaupin i have no idea. How would be it possible to read on a second-by-second basis without sending traffic? Are they just sending small amounts of data and estimating the 1 second capacity? That's what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To investigate bandwidth usage of any program use `iftop` tool. Install on your `Ubuntu` box using the following command:

```
apt-get install iftop
```

Then run it by (-n prevents it from host name lookup):

```
iftop -n
```

This tool shows bandwidth usage of every IP-IP communication.

Usually monitoring of bandwidth usage of any device in a network does not use noticeable bandwidth because these tools request status of every network node every second.